# Example of infinite sequences that produces different norms

Tags: numerical-methods, examples-counterexamples, normed-spaces

So I have an infinite sequence: $u = (u_1, u_2, u_3, . . .)$, where $u_j$ are real numbers. $l_1, l_2, l_\infty$ is defined as

$$||u||_1=\sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} |u_j|$$ $$||u||_2=\sqrt{\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|u_j|^2}$$

$$||u||_\infty=\sup_{j\in \mathbb{N}} |u_j|$$

I want to find an example such that $||u||_2 < \infty$, but $||u||_1$ is infinite. I have thought of examples between $||u||_1, ||u||_2$ and $||u||_\infty$, but I'm stuck on this one between $||u||_1$ and $||u||_2$

Comment: $(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: I thought about that too, but why is the squareroot of that sum finite?

Comment: Since $\sum (1/n^2)$ is finite.

Comment: @DavidMitra: then it can never be the other way around, right, where $||u||_1$ finite but $||u||_2$ infinite?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: How would you justify it other than giving this example?

Comment: $\lVert u\rVert_2^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert u_n\rvert\cdot \lvert u_n\rvert \leq \sup_{n} \lvert u_n\rvert \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lvert u_n\rvert = \lVert u\rVert_\infty\lVert u\rVert_1$?